# How to reference the current URL in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating an HTML 404 page and am trying to reference the current URL.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
  document.URL;
}
</script>
```

Currently, I'm using this, but it's appearing as a link not, for example, in an h1. Is there a solution?

Comment: What do you expect your function to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to manipulate the `DOM`

Use [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) to select the `<h1>` element, and [`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) to change the value of the `<h1>` to the current url.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.URL;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

Comment: Since document.URL is user input, I wouldn't recommend a direct output with `document.write()`.

Comment: @Olafant I fixed it